# Не запускается машина VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox

Дана Ubuntu c VirtualBox c созданной машиной под установку CentOS в образовательных целях. Но не смог запустить машину. При запуске выдает ошибку:

> The virtual machine 'cnt7' has terminated unexpectedly during startup
>   with exit code 1 (0x1).

И:

> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up
>   correctly. Please reinstall virtualbox-dkms package and load the
>   kernel module by executing
>
> 'modprobe vboxdrv'
>
> as root.
>
> If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign
>   the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before
>   you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for
>   more information.
>
> where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The
>   support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

Терминал говорит:

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Operation not permitted

Т.к. новичок, не знаю куда смотреть, беглый просмотр форумов по UEFI  с ее подписями и ключами не дал результатов. Подскажите хотя бы куда смотреть, так как не понятна сама "суть" проблемы. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: VirtualBox запускаете не под рутом.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install --reinstall virtualbox-dkms
```

Так же:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-generic
```